# How do you deal with the English text having Hindi words in between? (Text Mining in R)

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing sentiment analysis in R, and I'm looking for an effective way of dealing with Hindi language words in English text.

For eg:  "I know, magar this can happen"

Here "magar" is a Hindi word meaning "but". How to deal with such multi language text written in English?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you want to do ? Do you want to translate the hindi words, split the corpus in two ? Count frequencies?

Comment: Objective is to replace these these Hindi words written in english with English. I want to translate Hindi words to English.
I can make out some common Hindi words from the document, I want to replace those with English. Thanks!

Comment: Moreover I'm looking out for some effective ways to deal with such kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [phonetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm) like soundex to deal with out-of-vocabulary terms and to try to match them to hindi words. Then you translate those indie words into english.